# ModuleNotFound error only in Flask subfolders, not in root

Tags: python

I am having a very annoying problem with module imports within a Flask app.

This is my file structure:

```
root > app > views > tests
```

In the `views` folder, there is a file called `data.py`. I wish to import this into a file called `test_data.py` in `tests`:

```
from app.views import data
```

This gives a `ModuleNotFound` error, saying that `app` is not a module (I have added an `__init__.py` file, although I believe this is no longer needed in Python 3).

However, in the root (`foo`) folder, I have another file that is using exactly the same absolute import successfully:

```
from app.views import data
```

Can anybody help me out, please, with how I am able to import successfully into files other than the root folder?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

So, if your test_data.py is inside tests, and you wish to import data.py from views folder, you need to tell python to look into the folder specifically. You can do this in your test_data.py using this:

```
import sys
sys.path.insert(1, '/root/app/views')

import data
```

remember that the path is the absolute path. If you are on windows, this would start from C:/ or something and on linux from root. Do not use the relative path but only absolute.

Hope this helps!

Comment: Thank you, although I don't understand why I need to do this. My understanding is that Python should search through the entire folder structure for a module called "views".

Comment: Your solution is a bit better if I put the path to root instead of to views, as that ensures that the whole tree is accessible.

Comment: @Rob _My understanding is that Python should search through the entire folder structure for a module called "views"_ No, it does not do this. It looks in the current directory, and in all directories in `sys.path`.

Comment: @JohnGordon Thank you. So adding the project root to `sys.path` is just something I should be doing? Is it seen as the "correct" way of doing it?